# Does every continuous random variable have a pdf?

Tags: probability-theory

Does every continuous random variable have a pdf?

Is there any random variable which is neither discrete nor continuous?

Here, by continuous random variable I meant those random variables for which probablity of a singleton set is 0.

Comment: Have you looked up the definitions before you have asked these 3 questions? Btw, one question is enough for one post. And any attempt is welcomed.

Comment: I looked, but it didn't answer my question.Sorry to post multiple questions at once,but they are related

Comment: You want to check out a bit of Measure Theory to understand what you're wondering about

Comment: Above , by continuous random variable, I meant a random variable such that probability of any singleton set is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is a random variable with a [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution) (i.e. the uniform distribution on the Cantor set $\subset [0, 1]$) then $X$ is a continuous r.v. without a pdf.

[Lebesgue's decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem#Refinement) describes how any probability measure on $\Bbb{R}$ can be broken up into three parts with well-defined properties: a discrete part, a "pdf" part, and a singular part (one that's neither discrete nor has a pdf). So there's actually lots and lots of examples of continuous random variables that don't have pdfs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Is there any elementary counterexample?

Comment: When you say "elementary", what do you have in mind?

Comment: Actually, I just begin to learn probability, so i expect an example which is easy to digest.

Comment: This example is the simplest one I know of, and probably the "textbook" example of a continuous r.v. without a pdf. I doubt there are examples you would consider "more digestible". Anyway, your question has been answered (in the affirmative) and an example of such a random variable has been provided for you. This should be helpful in developing your intuition about continuous random variables going forward.